# stripe connect intent with direct charge

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to migrate from charges to payment intents for a [direct-charge flow](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/direct-charges#direct-intents) with connected customers.

I have the clientside code that handles `stripe.createPaymentMethod` and sends the paymentMethodId to the server.

My serverside code looks like this:

```js
  const intent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create(
                {
                    amount: parseInt(amount),
                    currency,
                    confirmation_method: 'manual',
                    confirm: true,
                    metadata,
                    payment_method: id,
                    customer: customerId,
                    off_session: true,
                },
                {
                    stripe_account: restaurantStripeAccountId,
                },
            );
```

I'm adding `stripe_account` as the account of my connected customer - `acct_xxxx`

Now when testing, cards without 3D secure are working fine - `42424242...`
but cards with 3D secure such as `4000000000003220` which is coming from [here](https://stripe.com/docs/testing#three-ds-cards)

I get :

```
Error: Your card was declined. This transaction requires authentication
```

In my `catch` clause, before it can even begin my 3D secure roundtrip flow with the client.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the `off-session` parameter, when you pass this parameter, it means that you want to create a charge where the customer is not present to authorize the 3DS, thus Stripe will try to complete the transactions.

This will obviously fail since the card requires 3DS.

You will need to pass `off-session=false` in this case.

And to make the `off-session=true` working in the future, you would need to `Setup` this card by passing

```
off-session=false,
setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
```

Hope the above helps

Comment: Thanks. This solved it - 
My other issue is that for this work, I had to add the connected customer accountId in the client side when I initiate stripe, as mentioned [here](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-methods/connect#creating-paymentmethods-directly-on-the-connected-account)
It doesn't make sense to me that when I initate stripe on the client I need to provide this, its a dynamic value and can chance. Any idea if this is the real solution or is there a backend-only way to do this as well?